# Names in Python dataframe which can have both values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this one

```
df.head()
NAME     DATE             FLAG
Test1    1 April 2020     Before
Test2    20 May 2020      Before
Test1    28 May 2020      Before
Test3    2 June 2020      After
Test2    3 June 2020      After
```

I want to create another dataframe which has the list of names which has flag value 'Before' but NOT 'After'
Like in Sets, it would be something like A intersection B-complement.

Using the df dataframe above, I will get only one name in my new dataframe - Test1.

I am struggling with how to structure the logic and what function to use.
Should I use a loop to go over all values or separate the dataframe based on flag value and perform a set operation?

Just looking for solution that works

Comment: `df[df.FLAG=='Before']`?

Comment: That would only filter out rows which have the FLAG value as 'Before'
The idea is to look at names which have FLAG='Before' but not 'After' 

Like Test1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach with `.loc[]`, which can prevent the `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning in some cases (which may not be an issue here).

```
# Find the NAME such that FLAG == After:
after = df.loc[ df['FLAG'] == 'After', 'NAME' ]

# Filter rows (before comma in .loc[]) and select columns (after comma)
before = df.loc[~df['NAME'].isin(after), ['NAME', 'DATE']]

print(before)
    NAME          DATE
0  Test1  1 April 2020
2  Test1   28 May 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

You' just need to do two filters; The first filter to check the `flag`, and then the second filter to remove anything that has an after flag:

```py
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                    
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test1', 'test2'], 'flag':['before', 'before', 'after', 'before', 'after']})       
df[~df.name.isin(df[df.flag=='after']['name'])]                                                                                                                                                       
 
    name    flag
0  test1  before
3  test1  before
```

Comment: Exactly what I was gonna post +1. But I prefer using column names-as-keys style rather than the as-attribute style: `df[~df['NAME'].isin(df[df['FLAG'] == 'After']['NAME'])]`